# Multi-variance products

Tags: database-design, erd, orm, eav

My current system houses different variants of Products in different tables;

- Productgroups
- Productcolors
- Productsizes
- Productmodels

Products can reside under 1 Productgroup and can have multi-variance Colors, Sizes and Models.

The logic on filling the database now fully relies on the website-scripts; meaning when I make a new Product in my back-office I am filling and relating the Colors, Sizes and Models to the product and make sure they have a combination of themselves.

This structure quickly grows; like 3 Color-variants of 6 Sizes and 2 Models already convert into 36 different products.

I wonder if there is a more logical way to this Database-wise. The problem is that in the future it might be possible that a product will get another property (let's say Sublabel). How could I make this method ever-extendable?

I read about [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), but that's really too much info to go on for now. Before I dive in the deep, I wonder if there are other approaches on this matter.

Comment: Please provide the full design you have now (columns, primary keys, foreign keys, other constraints, whatever you have) and not only table names.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to go for a full EAV solution, you could try something like this:

```
product_base
------------
  id
  product_group_id
  (other fields)


product_option_types
--------------------
  id
  description

product_options
---------------
  id
  product_id (fk to product_base.id)
  product_option_type_id (fk to product_option_types.id)
  description
```

This will let you have data that looks like this:

```
product_base
ID  |  name | product_group_id
------------|-----------------
1   |  Foo  | 1

product_option_types
ID  |  description
------------------
1   |  colour
2   |  size
3   |  model
4   |  sublabel

product_options
ID  | product_id | product_option_type_id  | description
---------------------------------------------------------
1   |  1         | 1                       | red
2   |  1         | 1                       | green
3   |  1         | 2                       | small
4   |  1         | 2                       | large
5   |  1         | 3                       | special edition
6   |  1         | 3                       | standard edition
7   |  1         | 4                       | Bar
```

So you end up with a "Foo" product that has 2 colours (red and green), two sizes (small and large), two models (standard and special) and a sublabel (Bar).

Note that in `product_options`, you'll need a unique constraint on `(product_id, product_option_type_id, description)`.

you could try to go further and attempt to normalize the values of `product_options.description` to a separate table, but that might be more complicated than it's worth.

Comment: I can see why you choose this design, but it's also important to point out the disadvantages. if you want to check if the product line has a Blue , Large , Special Edition T-Shirt you'll have to access the product_options table 4 times (once for each product_option) or do a nasty pivot. this is a classic example of the trade of between flexibility and speed. personally, i think that you'll query the table much more often then you'll add attributes.

Comment: @haki: Yes, that's a fair point. I suppose views could be created to filter on specific `product_option_type_id`s, but that wouldn't resolve any possible performance problems, it would just make queries a little more readable.